# weblogic.application.AnnotationProcessingException in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, ejb

I am trying to build a EAR file which contains my EJB modules. The project build works perfectly but when I try to deploy publish and deploy it in server I always get the following exception. Can anyone let me know if this an eclipse IDE issue. Is there any setting to be changed to make this work. All my other team mates were able to get this running but I couldn't.

```
Error processing annotations: ."
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception preparing module: EJBModule(AdvanceSearch.jar)
An error occurred while reading the deployment descriptor. The error was:
 Error processing annotations: .
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:447)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:188)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:83)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.application.AnnotationProcessingException: [EJB:015002]Unable to load class services.AdvanceSearchBean in Jar D:\LISModel\AdvanceSearch\build\classes : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'services.AdvanceSearchBean'
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EJBJarUtils.getIdentityAnnotatedClasses(EJBJarUtils.java:129)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.ModuleExtensionContextImpl.getAnnotatedClasses(ModuleExtensionContextImpl.java:64)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.metadata.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.createReadOnlyDescriptor(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:352)
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EjbDescriptorFactory.createReadOnlyDescriptor(EjbDescriptorFactory.java:78)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBMetadataHandler.loadDescriptors(EJBMetadataHandler.java:150)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a mismatch in class *services.AdvanceSearchBean* and how this is referenced in the deployment descriptor of module *AdvanceSearch.jar*. Maybe check consistency of referenced packages.